# Xml parse object inside of list of objects inside object using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

**XML FILE**

```
<Lines>
    <LineEntity>
      <Id>33947</Id>
      <Name>SEC_137438957044</Name>
      <IsUnderground>true</IsUnderground>
      <R>0.209</R>
      <ConductorMaterial>Steel</ConductorMaterial>
      <LineType>Cable</LineType>
      <ThermalConstantHeat>2400</ThermalConstantHeat>
      <FirstEnd>41990</FirstEnd>
      <SecondEnd>41992</SecondEnd>
      <Vertices>
        <Point>
          <X>407566.68007470988</X>
          <Y>5013899.3558040857</Y>
        </Point>
        <Point>
          <X>407625.00589398207</X>
          <Y>5013876.8697334668</Y>
        </Point>
        <Point>
          <X>407717.51971015992</X>
          <Y>5014160.9525629422</Y>
        </Point>
        <Point>
          <X>407559.40091708023</X>
          <Y>5014220.4665799234</Y>
        </Point>
      </Vertices>
    </LineEntity>
</Lines>
```

I want to get this `Vertices` object with Points, but I don't know how to get to it. What I tried so far:

```
var lines = xdoc.Descendants("LineEntity")
                 .Select(line => new Line
    {
        Id = (double)line.Element("Id"),
        Name = (string)line.Element("Name"),
        ConductorMaterial = (string)line.Element("ConductorMaterial"),
        IsUnderground = (bool)line.Element("IsUnderground"),
        R = (decimal)line.Element("R"),
        FirstEnd = (int)line.Element("FirstEnd"),
        SecondEnd = (int)line.Element("SecondEnd"),
        LineType = (string)line.Element("LineType"),
        ThermalConstantHeat = (int)line.Element("ThermalConstantHeat"),
        Vertices = line.Descendants("Vertices").Select(p => new Point {
        X = (decimal)p. //can't access Element
    })
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to get the descendant Point (not Vertices). List<Point> Vertices = line.Descendants("Point").Select(p => new Point((decimal)p.Element("X"),(decimal)p.Element("Y"))).ToList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code:

```
 ThermalConstantHeat = (int)line.Element("ThermalConstantHeat"),
 Vertices = line.Element("Vertices").Descendants("Point").Select(p => new TokenController.Point
 {
     X = (decimal)p.Element("X"),
     Y = (decimal)p.Element("Y")//can't access Element
 }).ToList()
```

you must first find **Element("Vertices")** then to find the **Descendants("Point")** List

Comment: You do not need to find Vertices to get Point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `Elements` of `Point` inside `Elements` of `Vertices` like

```
var lines = xdoc.Descendants("LineEntity")
    .Select(line => new Line
    {
        //Your rest of code same here

        Vertices = line.Elements("Vertices").Elements("Point").Select(p => new Point 
        {
            X = (decimal)p.Element("X"),
            Y = (decimal)p.Element("Y"),
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]